# Migrating project to VC++ 2015: AtlAxGetControl returns NULL

Tags: com, atl

I have migrated my project from VC++ 2010 to VC++ 2015.
It successfully compiled, but then I got an error on runtime:

> Unknown Error

While debugging I found out that `AtlAxGetControl()` returns `NULL` to `IUnknown`.
This is the code:

```
IUnknown *pUkn = NULL;
AtlAxWinInit();
if(m_hGraphCtrl)
    ::DestroyWindow(m_hGraphCtrl);

LPCWSTR szClassName = NULL;
#if _MSC_VER >= 1500
    szClassName = _T("AtlAxWin140");
#elif _MSC_VER > 1200
    szClassName = _T("AtlAxWin71");
#else
    szClassName = _T("AtlAxWin");
#endif

szClassName = CAxWindow::GetWndClassName();

if(SWAP_VIDEO)
{
    HWND hWnd =         g_InspectionPropSheet.m_cInspectionDlg.m_ModelView.GetSafeHwnd();
    m_hGraphCtrl = ::CreateWindow(szClassName, _T("GraphCtrl.GraphObj"),WS_CHILD, 0, 0, GetZoomOneSize(), GetZoomOneSize(), hWnd, NULL, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), NULL);
}
else
{
    CLSID clsid;
    CLSIDFromProgID(L"GraphCtrl.GraphObj", &clsid);
    LPOLESTR pOleStr; 
    StringFromCLSID(clsid, &pOleStr); 
    CString clsidstr = pOleStr;
    m_hGraphCtrl = ::CreateWindow(szClassName, clsidstr.GetBuffer(),WS_CHILD, 0, 0, GetZoomOneSize(), GetZoomOneSize(), this->m_hWnd, NULL, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), NULL);
}
HRESULT hrTemp = (HRESULT) GetLastError();
AtlAxGetControl(m_hGraphCtrl, &pUkn);//It returns pUkn NULL
if(pUkn)
    pUkn->QueryInterface(IID_IGraphObj, (void**)&pGraphObj);
```

Comment: Could you post the complete details of your error?

Comment: I improved the formatting of the code, changed the title and fixed some spelling errors.